# Importing labels for check in/out from an SDE to file geodatabase

Tags: esri-geodatabase, spatial-database, labeling

I am working on a large project where I am using the ArcMap 10 'distributed geodatabase' feature to check out a file geodatabase from our SDE file. I have tried several ways to avoid having to manually re-label the point features once I have checked out, but come up short every time.

I have saved the symobology to a layer file and can import that easily once checked out, but as far as the labels go, I cannot seem to easily import those. Is there any way to save the labeling with the layer, or is manually labeling the points through the properties menu the only way? *Any* suggestions are greatly appreciated and I will be happy to clarify if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see your delimna.
I would try to get the lyr file and drag it in (even if with broken links).
Then change the source to the file gdb.
Rather manual.
I think the only workaround is to utilize representations in the db.
But I do not recommend that route.
I spent a lot of time trying to make reps work for my application and finally removed them.